# Original data type reference when using Sql_Variant

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-variant

I am creating a table with an SQLVariant data type.  The values stored within the variant column could be **string**, **integer**, and/or **datetime**.  I read about the pitfalls of sqlvariant, but as the column isn't being indexed, or used in WHERE clauses, it seems the best choice.  However, I need to store a reference to the appropriate data type that the SqlVariant should be cast from/to.

In Microsoft .Net (my application), each [SQL data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) has an underlying numeric value:

[image]

I can't see an equivalent system in TSQL, so was wondering how I reference what each data type should be when using it.  Is there an *"ID"* for each TSQL data type?

The reason for this requirement is that the client passes the values as XML to a procedure, which saves the values into the table, e.g.

```
<parameters>
    <p ID="1" Value="2017-04-28" Type="?????" /> Perhaps the SqlDbType integer value from above (4), or an equivalient TSQL identifier?
    <p ID="2" Value="123" Type="Integer" />
    <p ID="3" Value="123.456" Type="Double" />
    <p ID="4" Value="Foo Bar" Type="String" />
</parameters>
```

Should I just use the SqlDbType value from .Net, or is there a better way?

### UPDATE

Think I might have found something...

```
SELECT * FROM sys.types
```

Is `system_type_id` the value I need here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user-defined table type to pass array of parametes as table-valued parameter:

SQL Code:
`CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE (ID int, Value Sql_Variant)`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME 
    @Values dbo.MyType READONLY
AS
    --@Values is usual table variable (but readonly) and you can select from it like from tables in database
    INSERT INTO SomeDBTable
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Values V
    WHERE V.ID <= 100500
```

.NET Code

```
DataTable dtList = new DataTable();
List<SqlDataRecord> filterList = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> filter in arrFilterList)
{
    SqlDataRecord record;

    record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[] { new SqlMetaData("ID", SqlDbType.Int),
                                      new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Variant) });
    record.SetInt(0, filter.Key);
    record.SetValue(1, filter.Value);
    filterList.Add(record);
}
SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_NAME", connection);
oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Values", filterList.Count > 0 ? filterList : null);
oCommand.Parameters["@Values"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
oCommand.Parameters["@Values"].TypeName = "dbo.MyType";
```

Comment: There also a table of type mappings,  but table-valued type is better than xml https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @EvilDr I wrote my answer because I think that passing paramters in ADO.NET in xml is bad practice

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you.  Won't your .Net code be translated to a string-based EXEC SP_NAME anyway, which is essentially the same thing (the parameters being sent as text)?

Comment: TVP are passed in native format, not a string. if your command have `CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` there no `EXEC SP_NAME` string. ADO.NET will use RPC to execute stored procedure

Comment: Profiler will show it as EXEC, but it's only visualisation of a query

Comment: So you created your own data base type to run with this, correct?

Comment: Yes, I've created it. Sometimes creating datatypes is a big problem. When you want to change it you should drop all objects that references it before.

Comment: Can you please expand your code to show how you retrieve the data from `filterList` in your stored procedure?  I've got a lot of learning to do here I think...

Comment: I've added example - you can use it like usual table (but readonly)

Comment: Sorry, but could you please post the definition of your `MyType ` SQL object.  I'm just reading about `SqlDataRecord`on MSDN, which seems like a really smart way of doing things

Comment: In the beginning: `CREATE TYPE dbo.MyType AS TABLE (ID int, Value Sql_Variant)`

Comment: You can also pass DataTable instead of IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>, but I can't make it work with `Sql_Variant`. But with other structures (array of IDs for example) DataTable easier than IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>